# WP8 Ads are not appearing

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, ads

I am trying to get Windows Advertising into my App, but nothing shows up.

I know the XAML control is correct because when I put in the default values I get the Microsoft Advertising banner.

I eventually hooked onto the ErrorOccurred event and the AdErrorEventArgs keep returning with "no ad available" which I am not sure what that means.

The stack trace I keep getting is:

```
at Microsoft.Advertising.Shared.AdvertisementFactory.CreateFromResponse(String response, AdDownloadCompleteCallback adDownloadCompleteCallback)
at Microsoft.Advertising.Shared.AdPlacement.CreateAdvertisement(Byte[] bytes)
at Microsoft.Advertising.Shared.AdPlacement.AdRequestComplete(IWebRequestWrapper request)
```

I have tried running it app on my device while debugging and not debugging and I have yet to see any advertising.

At the time of writing my category is set to Lifestyle - Art + Entertainment

Comment: Are you sure that you enabled all of the correct Capabilities in your app? There are a few wonky ones for Ads MSDN Doc http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/advertising-mobile-windows-phone-manifest-capabilities(v=msads.20).aspx

Comment: I unfortunately do have all of the required Capabilities enabled.  I believe that @anderZubi is correct in that there are just no ads in the "ads inventory" for my app. But a big thank you for a suggestion!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"no ad available" error means just that. There is no ad inventory available. It is the most typical behavior outside US.

The control is probably working fine, but PubCenter is not serving ads for your app. In my apps I have noticed that the performance of PubCenter is very poor outside United States.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! I do live outside of the U.S and have been burned by promotions that are for U.S citizens only so I am not surprised they get the priority for ads in the ad inventory.